# Different output - same script python executed from terminal vs script bash

Tags: python, bash

I have a python script doing some processing with threads and files. When I run it from the terminal is working well, getting the expected output but then I put this command inside a file called script.sh to make execution easier:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/local/bin/python3 myscript.py
```

Then I run the script:

```
./script.sh
```

but output is not the same.

I can't find what the problem is. Probably is related with the way process is created, maybe takes a different environment configuration when I run the script but I don't know how I can make it work from script.sh. No issues with my python script, has been tested a lot and works.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Without seeing the script it's hard to say what the problem could be. Please create a [mre] that we can run ourselves.

Comment: It's a huge python script but I'll try to do it. thanks

Comment: What is the output you _do_ get, if any?
And how is the output created? e.g. simple `print()` statements or are you using a logging library or something else?

Comment: Is the python script dependant on some non-`export`ed environment variables? You could dump the environment before running the bash script and dump it inside the bash script to compare

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: Add `env > env.1` inside the bash script. Do `env > env.2` before running the bash script. Afterwards, `diff env.1 env.2`

Comment: Try with adding the this line to .sh file and it will add appropriate environment: source ~/.bash_profile

Comment: @TedLyngmo you were right. Difference between env vars. I had a limitation with number of threads created inside script.sh so that's the reason why I got this difference. Thanks so much. I spent 2 days checking on it.

Comment: @Julio Great! You're welcome!